# Unpack a dictionary to format

Tags: python

I have a dict which is not the final output:

```
mydict = {'yesterday':'2017-10-19','today':'2017-10-20','tomorrow':'2017-10-21'}
```

I expect to return it as a prompt within `__str__` like:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}:{}, {}:{}, {}:{}".format(**mydict)
    #just for explaining
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of the `str.format` method?

Comment: what is the difference between your expected output and just using print?

Comment: example," {} was {}, {} is {},  {}would be{}".format(**mydict) @TanWeiLian

Comment: `"{0[0]}:{0[1]}, {1[0]}:{1[1]}, {2[0]}:{2[1]}".format(*mydict.items())` produces the desired output, but surely there's a better way than that.  Keep in mind that most versions of Python will not necessarily preserve the order of the items in your dict!

Comment: great reminder. @jasonharper

Comment: Please do a favor to cancel downvote. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @DFK I did not downvote.

Comment: My apology @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpacking a dictionary to `format` gives named arguments, so you need to name the placeholders as well; you might need:

```
mydict = {'yesterday':'2017-10-19','today':'2017-10-20','tomorrow':'2017-10-21'}
​
"yesterday:{yesterday}, today:{today}, tomorrow:{tomorrow}".format(**mydict)
# 'yesterday:2017-10-19, today:2017-10-20, tomorrow:2017-10-21'
```

---

If you need to format the keys, flatten the key values pairs from the dictionary (this doesn't guarantee the order unless you have an ordered dictionary initially), then unpack:

```
"{}:{}, {}:{}, {}:{}".format(*(x for kv in mydict.items() for x in kv))
# 'today:2017-10-20, tomorrow:2017-10-21, yesterday:2017-10-19'
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining `(x for kv in mydict.items() for x in kv)` ? I have no idea what the `for x in kv` means at the end (can you show a more of a lower level code?)